DataDog metric sum vs DB count
I have a service that inserts data to postgres DB table and logs a DD metric with the number of inserted records. The problem is that when I query the count from DB for some interval it differs a lot from the metric sum for the same interval, DB count is always 2-4 times bigger, for example DD metric shows 460k for 1 day, and the db query shows 1.2M records inserted.
I use tracer.dogstatsd.increment to send my metric. There are two tasks in ECS with my service and dd agent.
Here is DD graph data:
    "title": "Total records",
    "type": "query_value",
    "requests": [
        {
            "response_format": "scalar",
            "queries": [
                {
                    "data_source": "metrics",
                    "name": "query1",
                    "query": "sum:my_service.table_inserts{$env}.as_count()",
                    "aggregator": "sum"
                }
            ],
            "formulas": [
                {
                    "formula": "query1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "autoscale": true,
    "precision": 2,
    "timeseries_background": {
        "yaxis": {},
        "type": "bars"
    }
}

What is causing such discrepancy? I expect that the numbers were pretty close. Also I checked the logs and I dont see any errors neither in service nor in datadog agent.
